# class MyClient(discord.Client):AttributeError: partially initialized module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from utils import *

intents = discord.Intents.all()
Bot=commands.Bot(commands_prefix = "$",intents=intents)

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("yhsxiBot is online!")

Bot.run(TOKEN)
```

как решить проблему
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\nursu\Documents\mainbot.py", line 1, in

import discord

File "c:\Users\nursu\Documents\discord.py", line 3, in

class MyClient(discord.Client): AttributeError: partially initialized module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client' (most likely due to a circular import)

Answer (score -1):

На портале разработчика включите все пункты, и напишите простой код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents, fetch_ofline_members=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("yhsxiBot is online!")

client.run(token=TOKEN)
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ,только к сожелению у меня ничего не поменялось.как стоит ошибка та же таки стоит на месте.